# How to publish nuget package with the same version?

Tags: nuget

I have release version: 1.90. Is it possible to keep this version when I was doing patch updates for my library?

Currently when I am trying to publish with the version 1.90 it shows me the error: "Unable to process request. 'A package with id "TrakopolisAPI" and version '1.90 already exists and cannot be modified.''"

Comment: Maybe it is impossible at all?

Comment: I think you should change the minor version. Unless you can delete the old package i don't think you can publish with the exact same version number

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense to keep more minor versions. Thank you!

Comment: Please set it as an answer I will mark it as answered

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the minor version. Unless you can delete the old package i don't think you can publish with the exact same version number

Comment: Thank you! I will follow this logic

Answer (score 0):

exact same version number is not allowed if you delete a package it is immutable. Not listed but not really deleted. You cannot create that version to overwrite the same package.